# How to get the lines in one file which contain a string(with repetition) in another file?

Tags: python, linux, bash, file

File 1:

```
a
a
b
c
d
```

File 2:

```
a a1
b b1
e e1
f f1
```

My desired output:

```
a a1
a a1
b b1
```

I am trying to implement this using bash or Python.

In python I tried:

```
f1=open("file1")
f2=open("file2")
dpo1=f1.readlines()
dpo2=f2.readlines()

for i in dpo2:
    for j in dpo1:
        if j in i:
            print i
```

In bash I tried:

```
awk 'NR == FNR { ++h[tolower($1)]; next; } h[tolower($1)]' file1 file2
```

But this does not consider repetitions. It will give the output

```
a a1
b b1
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What did the python code do?

Comment: checked for only the last string in file 1. Which returned a single match instead of returning a match for all other strings in the file. (in reality my file1 is a subset of file2 that's why i know this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it using awk:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}$0 in a{print $0,a[$0]}' file2 file1
a a1
a a1
b b1
```

Read the key-value pairs from the second file into the array `a`, then print the ones that match.

Answer (score 3):

join is exactly what you need:

```
$ join f1 f2
a a1
a a1
b b1
```

see `man join` for more details

Answer (score 1):

You could make a dictionary from the second file and map each key from the first file to its corresponding value:

```
text = open("file2.txt").read().splitlines() 

keys = [i.split()[0] for i in text]
values = [i.split()[1] for i in text]
dic = dict(zip(keys, values))

# Now you have:
#dic = {'b': 'b1', 'e': 'e1', 'f': 'f1', 'a': 'a1'}

text = open("file1.txt").read().splitlines()

try:
    for word in text:
        print(word, dic[word])
except KeyError:
    pass
```

The output is:

```
a a1
a a1
b b1
>>>
```

Comment: `dic = dict(line.strip().split() for line in open("file2.txt"))`

Comment: Thank you! This is way more elegant than what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

First read `file2`, then read `file1`

```
awk '{if(FNR==NR) {# first file
          data[$1]=$2}
      else { # second file
          if($1 in data) print $1, data[$1]}' file2 file1
```

The internal variables `NR` and `FNR` are, respectively, the number of the current record in the input stream and the number of the record in the current file, so they're equal only when `awk` is reading the 1st file.

If we're reading the 1st file, we build an *associative array* containing the second field, indexed by the first one.

If we're reading the first file, we check if the single field in it is contained in the associative array (the check is made on the *indices* of the associative array) and if we find a match we output the current key and the corresponding value.